# Is there a way to keep active GestureDetector on the screen when the bottom sheet is showing?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, bottom-sheet

I'm using the [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package to display a `bottomSheet`.

I want users to be able to click on the screen when my bottom sheet is opened, like the following image.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: I would say that you need to see this as a stack widget shown on the screen rather than a bottom sheet

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code.

Comment: I don't have enough information about `Getx` so , on usual way you can set `isDismissible = false` in `showModalBottomSheet` more info at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html

Comment: There is no known gesture issue with `bottomSheet`, you should upload you code.

Comment: You can try DraggableScrollableSheet widget, it allows you use gesture behind it, bottomSheet will not allow you any gesture until you close it

Comment: I never used GetX, But in GestureDetector can you try setting a value of the `excludeFromSemantics` as a `true` when BottomSheet is open? That should do the job.

Comment: [A deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74922290/is-there-a-way-to-keep-active-gesturedetector-on-the-screen-when-the-bottom-shee/74964563#74964563) is the subject for [a meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385415/what-should-i-do-if-i-want-to-find-out-more-information-as-to-why-an-answer-was) ([ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)-related.).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The answer is *no*

---

#### Why?

According to [the Flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html):

> A modal bottom sheet is an alternative to a menu or a dialog and **prevents the user from interacting with the rest of the app.**

The *main* purpose of the bottom sheet is to prevent the user from interacting with the rest of the app.

---

#### How can we *overcome* this?

Use a [persistent bottom sheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showBottomSheet.html), i.e., using `showBottomSheet`.

> A closely related widget is a persistent bottom sheet, which shows information that supplements the primary content of the app **without preventing the user from interacting with the app.**

#### Output:

[image]

[image]

#### Code:

```
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: showSheet(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class showSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const showSheet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<showSheet> createState() => _showSheetState();
}

class _showSheetState extends State<showSheet> {
  void displayPersistentBottomSheet() {
    Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet<void>((BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        height: 200,   //  Change this according to your need
        child: const Center(child: Text("Image Filter Here")),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FilledButton(
        onPressed: displayPersistentBottomSheet,
        child: const Text(
          'Draggable Widget Here',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

#### Can it be done using Getx?

Unfortunately ***no***, because `getx` supports only `bottomShet` which is an alternative to *Modal Bottom Sheet* and there isn't any alternative to a persistent bottom sheet.

Comment: Nice. I had the same answer: "you can't". But I didn't post it since I thought _maybe_ there's a workaround...

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `Get.bottomSheet`, you can use a `Stack` widget and use it something like this:

```
Widget yourPhotoEditingWidget() {
  bool onShadowButtonTapped = false;
  return Stack(
    children: [
      Column(
        children: [
          yourDraggableWidget(),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.orange,
              onPressed: () {
                onShadowButtonTapped = !onShadowButtonTapped;
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Shadow',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      if (onShadowButtonTapped)
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            height: 150,
            width: 300,
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: const Center(
              child: Text(
                'Your Widget',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    ],
  );
}
```